# Statically positioned control bar like Gmail for iPhone web app?

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, safari

When viewing Gmail with an iPhone, they have it setup so that there is a statically positioned control bar at the top of the screen. Even if you scroll up and down on the page, it doesn't move. I'm curious if anyone know how they have set this up.

As far as I have heard in the past, it isn't possible to create fixed controls using CSS on iPhone's Safari. Instead it has to be something you hack together with Javascript. Do the same techniques work for Android's browser?

Ideas? Thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general the way this works is by overriding JavaScript touch handlers to prevent the default scrolling mechanism in the webpage. Then inside the touch handler you manually calculate touch physics and position the content in JavaScript.

- Since you asked about Gmail's implementation it's worth noting that **the Gmail team blogged about their implementation here**: http://code.google.com/mobile/articles/webapp_fixed_ui.html
- iScroll which has been mentioned by other posters is probably the best known open source implementation: http://cubiq.org/iscroll
- Apple's own implementation of this is known as PastryKit but it isn't well documented and not open source: http://daringfireball.net/2009/12/pastrykit

Update: I just reread the question and noticed you were asking about Android (doh!). Looks like Android 2.2 added support for CSS fixed: http://kentbrewster.com/android-scroller/

Comment: Thanks for the blog link from Google. It looks like their solution still ended up being mostly a hack.

Comment: CSS based fixed positioning is supported in iOS 5 now. It's not a catch-all, but it might be OK for some apps on PhoneGap or something.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple CSS style:

```
.className{
position:fixed;
}
```

You are right in that `position:fixed;` doesn't work in Mobile Safari but I believe it does in Android.

Here is that script you were talking about to make it work in mobile Safari:

http://cubiq.org/scrolling-div-on-iphone-ipod-touch

Comment: OP explicitly stated that this answer doesn't work for an iPhone web app, which is what they're asking for...

Comment: Thanks. The script you linked to uses a timer, so it might be a little jerky. http://cubiq.org/scrolling-div-on-iphone-ipod-touch seems to imply that timers aren't optimal here.

Comment: I've tried it with timers before and they are indeed a little jerky. Gmail's is perfectly stationary, but I'm not sure how they've done it.

Comment: @kevboh - Your script is more complete, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with iOS web app development, but [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) looks promising.

Comment: That is for `overflow` not `position`?

Comment: It's for overflow and position. Check out the example: http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll/